# Laravel: Retrieve data inputted by user

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I'm quite new to Laravel and I'm confused with how I have to retrieve data inputted by certain users.

In my project, there is a user profile that should display all form submissions by the user.

Here is my controller function:

```
public function clientAccount(BookingRequest $bookings)
{
    $client = Client::whereUserId(Auth::id())->with('user')->first();
    $bookings = BookingRequest::with(Auth::id())->with('client')->first(); //unsure about here//
    return view('client.account', compact('client','bookings'));
}
```

Here is my model:

```
    public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Client', 'client_id', 'user_id');
}
```

How do I fix this?

EDIT:

I tried using this but somehow I don't get any display

```
$bookings = BookingRequest::where('client_id',Auth::id());
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I seemed to get this error  "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::parseWithRelations() must be of the type array, integer given, called in C:\Users\Daniela Echavez\Desktop\therapeace\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php on line 1036"

Comment: what is weird to me is the usage of the Booking model, are you sure your model is called `BookingRequest` or is it `Booking` ?

Comment: It's called BookingRequest

Comment: You need to check in the DB that you have entries for that client id in order to get results back. Because the usage of `with` is for relationship not based on id, so `BookingRequest::with('client')` will work if you have `client` function in your `BookingRequest` model.

Comment: I do have a `client` function in my `BookingRequest` model. Right now I'm still confused and I'm not sure if I'm calling the data right

Comment: I will respond in an answer as it is longer than a comment

Comment: The given answer is a better solution but to provide some input on your current solution. You are using `with(Auth::id())` the `with()` helper on a query expects a relation name not the user id so changing that with `where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())` would probably be enough to get a usable result, but do check out a relation on the User model as explained in the answer by @nakov.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks for all your responses!**

I'm now able to retrieve data by using this:

```
public function clientAccount()
{
    $client = Client::whereUserId(Auth::id())->with('user')->first();
    $bookings = $client->booking()->with('client')->get(); 
    return view('client.account', compact('client','bookings'));
}
```

and in my model, I used this instead

```
public function booking()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\BookingRequest', 'client_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the relationship needs to be one to many meaning one Client has many Bookings, than in your Client model you should have the following function:

```
public function bookings() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(BookingRequest::class);
}
```

then you just need to find the client, and for him you just use

```
$client->bookings()
```

it will list all the bookings for that client.

Comment: Your answer is correct @nakov but you might change it to `$client->bookings` as a closure. It's ok for `$client->bookings()->count()` or `$client->bookings()->first()`

Answer (score 0):

Following on from nakov:

```
public function clientAccount()
{
  $client = Client::whereUserId(Auth::id())->with('user')->first();
  $bookings = $client->bookings();

  return view ('client.account')->with('bookings', $bookings)
}
```

And in your user profile view:

```
foreach($bookings as $booking){
  // do something with each booking
  // e.g. var_dump($booking) to see the data you're working with
}
```